# Automated database table creation via Jenkins

Tags: database, maven, jenkins, build, continuous-integration

I have setup Jenkins to automatically build my Maven project. I would like to extend the same to automatically create database tables if they dont exist. Can this be done via jenkins? i.e. Can the Jenkins job be modified to have an additional pre-build step of creating database tables? If so, can anyone give me any pointers as to how to do this?
if this is not possible directly in Jenkins, can this be done via Maven? i.e. modify the Maven build to create the tables before compiling the code.

Any help will be useful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of database are you using? Postgres, Oracle, MySQL, ...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [sql maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/index.html) to execute sql-scripts or define pre-build steps in the jenkins job.
See this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185380/run-custom-database-scripts-in-jenkins) for more tips...

If you prefer not to use maven but a jenkins solution I would add a 'pre-build Step' or a 'Build-Step' (depends on your job-type) of the type 'Execute Shell' or 'Execute Windows batch command' and call the corresponding command line tool of your database (in this case [MySQL Command-Line Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html)).
The command line tool must be installed on the jenkins server or must be included in the project checkout.

Comment: I am using Mysql database. I have tried to use the sql maven plugin and that works. Is there a way to do this directly from Jenkins without having to use Maven? I'd like to keep my Maven file separate from the DB configuration

Answer (score 1):

As a solution, I used a separate Jenkins Job to run the SQL script via the Jenkins command line tool interface.

Comment: You have posted the same thing simvo has suggested you. Accept simvo's answer and delete this comment. It adds nothing to the post.